# Here API Indoor discovery

Tags: here-api

I am trying to get the venue list using the API
https://indoor-discovery.venue.maps.api.here.com/discovery/v2?app_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&app_code=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&at=31.2403,74.6354,8.6291,77.5743

The "at" parameter almost covers the country. but the results always come back as

```
{
    "hostname": "ip-10-13-214-44",
    "type": "venues",
    "status": {
        "code": "OK",
        "reason": "DISCOVERY_SUCCESSFULL"
    },
    "results": {
        "items": []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum value for the bounding box is at 100km x 100km. If you search within a smaller area you will get some results in the list. Here is one for the coverage of Chennai:

https://indoor-discovery.venue.maps.api.here.com/discovery/v2?app_id=yyy&app_code=xxxx&at=13.2403,79.8454,12.7291,80.5743

> {
>
> ```
> "hostname": "ip-10-13-214-44",
> "type": "venues",
> "status": {
>     "code": "OK",
>     "reason": "DISCOVERY_SUCCESSFULL"
> },
> "results": {
>     "items": [
>         {
>             "id": "DM_17331",
>             "title": "Phoenix Marketcity Mall",
>             "address": {
>                 "countryCode": "IND",
>                 "city": "Chennai",
>                 "postalCode": "600042",
>                 "street": "Radha Mohan Street",
>                 "house": ""
>             },
>             "position": [
>                 12.991487949990416,
>                 80.21652530007341
>             ],
>             "distance": 1045.380777404391,
>             "type": "urn:nlp-types:venue",
>             "vicinity": "Radha Mohan Street,600042,Chennai,IND",
>             "bbox": [
>                 [
>                     12.992687434189028,
>                     80.21572801724027
>                 ],
>                 [
>                     12.990288596080005,
>                     80.21732267846822
>                 ]
>             ],
>             "minFloor": -1,
>             "maxFloor": 3,
>             "namespace": "public"
>         },
>         {
>             "id": "DM_3869",
>             "title": "Maya Plaza",
>             "address": {
>                 "countryCode": "IND",
>                 "city": "Chennai",
>                 "postalCode": "600017",
>                 "street": "Sir Thyagaraya Road",
>                 "house": ""
>             },
>             "position": [
>                 13.041404800089397,
>                 80.23480899848522
>             ],
>             "distance": 6860.646286724997,
>             "type": "urn:nlp-types:venue",
>             "vicinity": "Sir Thyagaraya Road,600017,Chennai,IND",
>             "bbox": [
>                 [
>                     13.041557002816027,
>                     80.23472596161558
>                 ],
>                 [
>                     13.04125261448761,
>                     80.23489217568006
>                 ]
>             ],
>             "minFloor": 0,
>             "maxFloor": 4,
>             "namespace": "public"
>         },
>         {
>             "id": "DM_3866",
>             "title": "Challa Mall",
>             "address": {
>                 "countryCode": "IND",
>                 "city": "Chennai",
>                 "postalCode": "600017",
>                 "street": "Sir Thyagaraya Road",
>                 "house": ""
>             },
>             "position": [
>                 13.040501949969517,
>                 80.24325910031074
>             ],
>             "distance": 7183.4301593814025,
>             "type": "urn:nlp-types:venue",
>             "vicinity": "Sir Thyagaraya Road,600017,Chennai,IND",
>             "bbox": [
>                 [
>                     13.040704496188196,
>                     80.24306093132118
>                 ],
>                 [
>                     13.040299554031115,
>                     80.24345735684514
>                 ]
>             ],
>             "minFloor": -1,
>             "maxFloor": 1,
>             "namespace": "public"
>         },
>         {
>             "id": "DM_3871",
>             "title": "Kasi Arcade Mall",
>             "address": {
>                 "countryCode": "IND",
>                 "city": "Chennai",
>                 "postalCode": "600017",
>                 "street": "Sir Thyagaraya Road",
>                 "house": ""
>             },
>             "position": [
>                 13.040300249964666,
>                 80.24435859999508
>             ],
>             "distance": 7224.9813794400025,
>             "type": "urn:nlp-types:venue",
>             "vicinity": "Sir Thyagaraya Road,600017,Chennai,IND",
>             "bbox": [
>                 [
>                     13.040532567087016,
>                     80.24415738929856
>                 ],
>                 [
>                     13.04006805606027,
>                     80.24455999517599
>                 ]
>             ],
>             "minFloor": -1,
>             "maxFloor": 1,
>             "namespace": "public"
>         },
> ```

Comment: Hi there,Although the query you gave worked. I am trying with these coordinates 77.612164,12.931263,77.701794,12.927706 in Bangalore, it comes back with {
    "hostname": "ip-10-13-214-44",
    "type": "venues",
    "status": {
        "code": "OK",
        "reason": "DISCOVERY_SUCCESSFULL"
    },
    "results": {
        "items": []
    }
}

Comment: The bounding box you mentioned does not cover Bangalore it shows up somewhere in Greenland. Within this one you will get two malls back:  12.93,77.61,12.92,77.70  A bounding box is given as two WGS 84 coordinates with topLeftLat, topLeftLon, bottomRightLat, bottomRightLon

Comment: Trying with these coordinates  13.03, 77.50,12.92, 77.64 topleftlat, topleftlong & bottomrightlat, bottomrightlong I am sure these are withing Bangalore. But the results are  {
    "type": "ApplicationError",
    "_type": "ns2:RoutingServiceErrorType",
    "subtype": "InvalidInputData",
    "details": "Incorrect or missing input",
    "additionalData": [
        {
            "key": "at",
            "value": "13.03, 77.50,12.92, 77.64"
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 0):

I had copied the lat/long from google maps, then I realized that the longitude has space, in the beginning, I removed the space and it started to work!